# DRF PATCH method, got all values at type of string in request.data

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am sending axios.patch request with form-data in vue

```
axios.patch(`${API_BASE}/products/${id}/`, data, {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

and calling Django ModelViewset partial update

```
    class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            data = request.data.copy()
            question = self.get_object()
            ...
```

the problem is that I am getting all values in stringified form.. null values as 'null', integer values as '1', and so on. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URpUP.png)

What should I do to get normal values(null as None, integer as int) in request.data?

Comment: Use serializer and set `partial=True` in serializer initialisation. Eg: `serializer = YourSerializer(request, data=request.data, partial=True)`

Comment: @zaidfazil Thanks for reply, but the question is about "I receive null values as 'null' type of string in request.data. What should I do in order to receive null values as None in request.data?

Comment: `request.data` is always a `QueryDict`,. Serializers are used for interpreting the data from the request. Write a serializer for your data and the validated_data from the serializer would be of what you can use.

Comment: @zaidfazil got you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by setting null values as empty strings before the patch method  and by setting allow_null=True in serializers

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to get normal values(null as None, integer as int) in request.data?

Either use JSON or use the serializer's validated data.
HTML forms are sent as strings in the forms of key/value pairs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I can't use JSON, because my form contains images and I can't get validated data, because I am overriding ModelViewset's update method and getting the request.data in order to do some manipulation.

Comment: So it's down to you doing the cast yourself.